# Joint Probability Distribution Function

Tags: probability

For some Joint Probability Function on two continuous random variables, $f(x,y)$, is it true that the integral of $f(t,t)dt$ from negative infinity to infinity is necessarily upper bounded by one? I thought that $4xy$ is a counter example, but I can't seem to visualize what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that $f(x,y)$ is the *joint density* of jointly continuous random variables $X$ and $Y$, it is straightforward to show that the density 
of $Z = Y-X$ is given by
$$g(z) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x, z+x)\,\mathrm dx.$$
Thus your integral
$\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t,t)\,\mathrm dt$ can be recognized
as $g(0)$. I will leave it up to you to decide whether it is
true that $g(0) \leq 1$ for all possible pairs of jointly continuous
random variables.

Comment: I'm a little confused, why are we looking at Z = Y - X?

Comment: Further why is the intuition used below incorrect? That's what I'm getting confused about.

Comment: `why are we looking at` $Z = Y - X$?  We are not. I am just pointing out to you that the integral whose value you want to compute just happens to have the same value as the probability density function of a certain random variable, and asking you to think whether it is always the case that the value of a _density_ function is bounded above by $1$.

Answer (score -2):

Note that if your variables are $X,Y$ then
$$
\int_\mathbb{R} f(t,t)dt = \mathbb{P}[X=Y=t] \leq 1
$$

Comment: Note that this is not true. At all.

Comment: @Did is that integral not the probability that X=Y.